# Oracle SQL, concatenate multiple columns + add text

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

So I basically wanna display this (whole row in ONE column):

I like [type column] cake with [icing column] and a [fruit column].

The result should be:

```
Cake_Column
----------------

I like chocolate cake with whipped_cream and a cherry.

I like strawberry cake with vanilla_cream and a lemon_slice.

etc.

etc.
```

I need some sort of TO_CHAR statement that does ([column] "some text" [column]) "new_column_name";

What am I supposed to know?

Answer (score 185):

You have two options for concatenating strings in Oracle:

- [CONCAT](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat.php)
- [Using `||`](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat2.php)

CONCAT example:

```
CONCAT(
  CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      CONCAT(
        CONCAT('I like ', t.type_desc_column), 
        ' cake with '), 
      t.icing_desc_column),
    ' and a '),
  t.fruit_desc_column)
```

Using `||` example:

```
'I like ' || t.type_desc_column || ' cake with ' || t.icing_desc_column || ' and a ' || t.fruit_desc_column
```

Comment: This is really slow (to run, not really to type).  Is there any better way?

Comment: This is so ugly, with respect to an very old-brand DBMS. How come Oracle don't suppoer many-argument-version Concat? However, thanks to Shankar, there's a || operator.

Answer (score 94):

Did you try the **`||`** operator ?

[Concatenation Operator Documentation from Oracle >>>](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fundamentals.htm#CIHHHEJG)

Answer (score 51):

```
select 'i like' || type_column || ' with' ect....
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.  I like the '||' as it makes it easier to maintain the SQL query.

Answer (score 32):

Below query works for me @Oracle 10G ----

```
select PHONE, CONTACT, (ADDR1 ||  '-' || ADDR2 || '-' || ADDR3) as Address
from CUSTOMER_DETAILS
where Code='341';
```

O/P -

> 1111 abc@gmail.com 4th street-capetown-sa

Answer (score 17):

The `Oracle/PLSQL` `CONCAT` function allows to concatenate two strings together.

```
CONCAT( string1, string2 )
```

> string1
>
> The first string to concatenate.
>
> string2
>
> The second string to concatenate.

E.g.

```
SELECT 'I like ' || type_column_name || ' cake with ' || 
icing_column_name || ' and a ' fruit_column_name || '.' 
AS Cake FROM table;
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
SELECT 'I like ' || type_column_name || ' cake with ' || 
icing_column_name || ' and a ' fruit_column_name || '.' 
AS Cake_Column FROM your_table_name;
```

It should concatenate all that data as a single column entry named "Cake_Column".