# Concatenation of two columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle SQL, concatenate multiple columns + add text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619259/oracle-sql-concatenate-multiple-columns-add-text)

I need to write a query to that fetches values of two columns by merging it in certain format.

```
X          Y
-----      -----
10567      1 M
10568      1.5 M
10567      2.5 M
```

The result should be in the format

```
  "X - Y"
 1)10567 - 1 M
 2)10568 - 1.5 M
```

Any help would be really appreciated..

Comment: `||` is used for concatenation in Oracle. `SELECT X || ' - ' || Y FROM yourtable`