# How to merge (combine) 2 columns into 1 in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have 3 textfields where user types table name and 2 column names which need to be merged.

How should I merge (combine) 2 column values into 1?

I use oracle 11g enterprise

Comment: ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("Insert into " +table_name.trim()+(first_column_name.trim())+" values "+ (first_column_name.trim() || second_column_name.trim()));

Comment: I pass firs_column_name and second  one as an argument to sql statement, but it shows that is incorrect way of using || operator. Plz help! :)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by merge. Are you talking about combining two columns into one in your result set? or actually changing the table structure? or something completely different?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL, concatenate multiple columns + add text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619259/oracle-sql-concatenate-multiple-columns-add-text)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

concatenate?

```
select col1 || ' ' || col2 from tablex
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a very vague requirement. Concatenate the values maybe?

```
insert into sometable( Column1 )
values ( Column1 || Column2 );
```

If you need to specify the table name to INSERT into, then you will need to use dynamic SQL to achieve this. Would you need to specify the target column name as well? This example assumes you would use PL/SQL, which may not be appropriate in your case.

```
sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO '|| specified_table || '(' || merge_column || ') VALUES ( :1 )';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING column1 || column2;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes, I meant concatenate. Let me try this sql statement. I'll reply later :)

Comment: Yes, I need to specify target column. It can be new column or can replace one of the existing columns.

Comment: ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("Insert into " +table_name.trim()+(first_column_name.trim())+" values "+ (first_column_name.trim() || second_column_name.trim()));

Comment: I pass first_column_name and second one as an argument to sql statement, but it shows that is incorrect way of using || operator. Plz help! :)

Comment: Use '+'. That's what you are using to concatenate elsewhere in the DML string. '||' is used for concatenation in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could make another column (an auxiliary column ) and replace the other 2 columns with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Merging columns in Oracle Live

```
SELECT CONCAT (ENAME, JOB) from scott.EMP
```

the above command will merge `ENAME` and `JOB` columns, and these 2 different columns will be shown in a single column