# Display the UID and name of employees together in a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a table but don't know how to show two column data in single column
can some help me

Comment: provide sample data and your desired output in table fromat

Comment: table uploaded check https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbpNE.png   Here is the table i want to see emp_name and emp_uid in a single column only

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1619259/1509264 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/20268273/1509264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat()` function

```
select concat(emp_id, emp_name) as derive_col 
from yourtablename
```