# Returning multiple fields to a single, comma separated, field in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm running some queries where i need to return multiple fields of a table in one field as a comma separated string

i'm looking for something along these lines but i'm not sure of the exact code:

```
   SELECT STRINGUP('FIELD1', 'FIELD2', 'FIELD3')NEWFIELDNAME FROM ...
```

using Oracle SQL Developer

Cheers

Comment: Please do a little research. I searched for "concatenation string Oracle SQL stackoverflow".  Look at this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619259/oracle-sql-concatenate-multiple-columns-add-text.

Comment: Sorry, i'm pretty new to development, if i'd known it was called concatenation i'd have found it. thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'FIELD1' || ',' || 'FIELD2' || ',' || 'FIELD3' AS NEWFIELDNAME FROM ...
```