# Display array in combobox

Tags: arrays, vb.net, combobox

This is what I have that is giving me the unable to bind error

```
    Dim STSQL = <sql>SELECT Employee_id, First_name, MIDDLE_INITIAL, last_name,
       (Employee_id || ' ' || First_name || ' ' || last_name) As EmpName
    FROM mpcs.Employee</sql>.Value


    rsMPCS = MPCS_SELECT_SQL(UCase(STSQL), rsMPCS)

    dtEmp = New DataTable
    dtEmp.Load(rsMPCS)

    cboEmployee.DataSource = dtEmp
    cboEmployee.DisplayMember = "EmpName"
    cboEmployee.ValueMember = "ID"
```

Comment: I have no idea what `rsMPCS` or `MPCS_SELECT_SQL` are. The error is an Oracle one because on Oracle, CONCAT takes 2 and only 2 arguments.  So just glue several together: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat.php and shown here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619259/oracle-sql-concatenate-multiple-columns-add-text (assuming it *is* Oracle - I'm just going on the error, I thought you had MySQL for previous Qs).

Comment: You have apparently never used bound datasources.  The ValueMember and DisplayMember are supposed to be the names of the Properties or members you want to bind to.  In this case, they would be column names in the datatable.  You dont have a column named `Id`, use `Employee_id`

Comment: I am very novice I know.  Doing this on this site helps me tremendously though, I keep notes, I save everything and eventually I'll be better.  So now when I do `cboEmployee.SelectedValue` it will always give me the Employee_ID selected correct?

Answer (score 0):

first change this

```
Public ArrEmployee(3, 0) As String
```

to

```
Dim x as Integer = number of employees( if you don't know put it larger than expected)
Public ArrEmployee(x, 3) As String
```

Then this part should be this way

```
ArrEmployee(x, 0) = rsMPCS("Employee_id")
ArrEmployee(x, 1) = rsMPCS("First_name")
ArrEmployee(x, 2) = rsMPCS("MIDDLE_INITIAL")
ArrEmployee(x, 3) = rsMPCS("last_name")
x += 1
```

Finally when you want to add to combobox

```
For x = 0 To UBound(ArrEmployee, 2) - 1
    Dim textToAdd As String = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", ArrEmployee(x, 0), ArrEmployee(x, 1), ArrEmployee(x, 2), ArrEmployee(x, 3))
    cboEmployee.Items.Add(textToAdd)
Next
```

Said that, you should really make employee class and then list of that class. It would be easier in long run, neater and done properly.